# How to use SELECT statement with OUT parameters?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to get game name column from games table in OUT game_name parameter, which is using SELECT statement. Sadly, I get an error near "SELECT":

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.toggle(uid numeric, gid NUMERIC, OUT follow integer, OUT game_name TEXt)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
    BEGIN
perform FROM game_follows WHERE user_id = uid and game_id = gid;
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
        INSERT INTO game_follows(user_id, game_id) VALUES(uid, gid);
        follow := 1;
        game_name := SELECT name FROM games WHERE id = gid;

    ELSE
         DELETE FROM game_follows WHERE user_id = uid and game_id = gid;
        follow := 0;
        game_name := SELECT name FROM games WHERE id = gid;
    END IF;
    END;
$$
```

I would like it to return two values: if the game is being followed and what is the game name, which I then would send back via API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code looks little bit strange, but it can be fixed. You are searching [`SELECT INTO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW)

```
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                  FROM game_follows 
                 WHERE user_id = uid and game_id = gid)
  THEN
    INSERT INTO game_follows(user_id, game_id) VALUES(uid, gid);
    follow := 1;
  ELSE
     DELETE FROM game_follows WHERE user_id = uid and game_id = gid;
     follow := 0;
  END IF;
  -- ANSI syntax
  game_name := (SELECT name FROM games WHERE id = gid);
  -- or Postgres/Oracle syntax
  SELECT name INTO game_name FROM games WHERE id = gid;
  -- Postgres syntax
  SELECT name FROM games WHERE id = gid INTO game_name;
END;
```

The variable `follow` should be a `boolean`. Then in code there should be `follow := true` else `follow := false`.

Comment: Can you shortly explain how SELECT INTO works better than SELECT ?

Comment: @r.Die: All three syntax variants are equivalent. Neither is "better". Your original is just missing parentheses.